# How do I copy a file into a docker-cloud container? (AKA How to copy a file over ssh without using scp)

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, docker-cloud

docker-machine has an scp command, but docker-cloud doesn't seem to have any way to transfer a file from my local machine to the cloud container or vice-versa.

I'm submitting an answer below that I've finally figured out (in hopes that it will help someone), but I'd love to hear better answers if there are any!

(I realize docker-cloud is going away, but perhaps this will be helpful for other cloud platforms as well)

Answer (score 0):

To transfer a file from your local machine *to* a docker-cloud instance that is running linux with the `tee` command available:

```
docker-cloud container exec id12345 tee filename.ext < file_to_copy.ext > /dev/null
```

(you'll want to redirect output to `/dev/null` as shown unless you want the entire contents of the file to be echoed to the terminal... twice)

To transfer a file to your local machine, is somewhat easier:

```
docker-cloud container exec id12345 cat file_to_copy.ext > filename.ext
```

**Note:** I'm not sure this works for binary files, and it can even cause issues with linefeed characters in text files, based on terminal settings, etc. - but it's the best answer I've got short of using an external service like https://transfer.sh